# IR rays from mobile phones

Tags: iphone, galaxy, television

Is it possible to generate IR signals from a mobile phone the way TV controllers do? (Assuming TV controllers use IR signals). I mean do they have the required hardware in them. By mobile phones I mean phones like Galaxy S3, Iphone.

Thanks

Comment: Why all the vote downs? Its not a duplicate and this kind of information is not easy to find in mobile specifications...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the phone.  THe new Galaxy S4 should.  But its totally up to the manufacturer to add that hardware or not, so it really can't be answered without a specific model.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of Android devices do not have IR sensors or emitters, and hence cannot do this.

On the other hand, a lot of TVs these days allow remotes over Bluetooth and WiFi, so you may want to look into/contact the manufacturers to see if they offer an API.

Answer (score 1):

The device has to have an infrared transmitter, but very few devices do currently. The HTC One is one device that has one, and the upcoming Galaxy S4. So yes, it is certainly possible, but it does require a hardware component.